# Woocommerce - Remove 'Buy Product' Button + Make Product Thumbnails Clickable

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, buttons

I want to solve the following tasks in my Woocommerce website:

1) I need to remove the 'Buy Product' button from my Woocommerce catalog:

[image: Remove 'Buy Product' Button]

I could introduce a 'display: none' in my CSS file for that specific part but I prefer to remove it. All the tutorials I tested couldn't solve this task.

2) Make all product thumnails clickable to the external websites where users can order those products.

It was really surprising for me to conclude that this is not such a simple process as I thought it would be. In other CMS, this is relatively easy to do but couldn't find anything for WordPress/Woocommerce except this link - https://slocumthemes.com/2015/10/how-to-make-woocommerce-thumbnails-clickable/ - which didn't work because it might not be up to date.

Anyone can help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

1. try this for making thumbnails clickable
   https://themegrill.com/support-forum/topic/make-product-images-clickable-through-to-the-product-page/
2. under each product ( edit product) set it as external product and add url to external website

It also depends which theme you are using, maybe it overrides templates.